# What does Link Seams mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sinon, commonjs

I read these doc and article:

- https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417

I still don't understand what Link Seams are. What's this? Why use this? What problem does it solve?

The article above explains this concept using C++ programming language.

I am looking for an explanation using TypeScript/JavaScript and Nodejs. If you can provide a code example, that will be better.

Comment: This is an oversimplification but you can think of a "seam" as a "stub" or "mock" in terms of testing. The goal is to isolate behaviour from other external functionality by replacing them with your own. Basically it's a bit of a hack when you can't change the code to be more testable and isolated, so you divorce it from dependencies yourself by using workarounds to replace external calls with something you control - what would normally simply be a mock if you had direct access.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for reply. But I still don't understand. It's too abstract without code example.

Comment: Are you still looking for an explation? It is basically module replacement, replacing one module with another that you control for the test. I can write an elaborated answer with code.